# what does sqlite3.OperationalError: near "t": syntax error means

Tags: python, sqlite

I am using python and trying to update rows using

```
db=sqlite3.connect('db')
cursor=db.execute('select * from infos where is_processed=0')
films=cursor.fetchall()
cursor.close()
db.close()
for film in films:
    inputLayer=np.array([film[1],film[2],film[3]],dtype=float)
    name=film[0]
    #print inputLayer
    NeuralNetwork3.nn(inputLayer,film[4])
    sql="update infos set is_processed=1 where file_name='"+name+"'"
    db = sqlite3.connect('db')
    db.execute(sql)
    db.commit()
    db.close()
```

I get: sqlite3.OperationalError: near "t": syntax error what is wrong?
Note it points at line "db.excute(sql)" and says at that line is the error

Comment: What is the value of `name` when your code errors?

Comment: See also https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Side note: why do you connect and disconnet in the loop? That's really not neccessary.

Comment: khnelwood the name value is : /media/bassel/Data/Bassel/animations/THE PEANUTS MOVIE Final Trailer (2015) Charlie Brown Movie HD.mkv

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose `name` contains a single quote followed by a `t`, as in

```
name = "don't look now"
sql = "update foo set is_processed=1 where bar='"+name+"'"
```

Then `sql` would equal

```
In [156]: sql
Out[156]: "update foo set is_processed=1 where bar='don't look now'"
```

and sqlite3 will think the conditional is `where bar='don'` followed by a syntax error, `t look now'`. `sqlite3` then raises

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "t": syntax error
```

This is an example of why you should [always use parametrized SQL](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). To avoid this problem (and protect your code from SQL injection attacks), use parametrized SQL and pass a sequence (or, depending on the paramstyle, a mapping) of values as the second argument to [`cursor.execute`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15):

```
sql = "update foo set is_processed=1 where bar=?"
cursor.execute(sql, [name])
```

When you pass arguments (such as `[name]`) as the second argument to
`cursor.execute`, sqlite3 will escape the single-quote for you.

---

Per the [Python Database API](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id44), when you pass `parameters` as the second argument to `cursor.execute` (my emphasis):

> The module will use the `__getitem__` method of the parameters object to map
>     either positions (integers) or names (strings) to parameter values. This
>     allows for both sequences and mappings to be used as input.
>
> The term bound refers to the process of binding an input value to a database
>     execution buffer. **In practical terms, this means that the input value is
>     directly used as a value in the operation. The client should not be required
>     to "escape" the value so that it can be used** — the value should be equal to
>     the actual database value

---

Here is a runnable toy example to help see the problem and how it is avoided using parametrized SQL:

```
import sqlite3

with sqlite3.connect(':memory:') as conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE foo
                 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                  bar TEXT,
                  is_processed BOOL)''')
    name = "don't look now"

    sql = "update foo set is_processed=1 where bar='"+name+"'"
    print(sql)
    cursor.execute(sql)

    # comment out `cursor.execute(sql)` above and compare with
    # sql = "update foo set is_processed=1 where bar=?"
    # cursor.execute(sql, [name])
```